# Cannot find Lombok plugin in Android Studio 2021.1.1 (build of 2022)

Tags: android-studio, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin, android-studio-plugin

After installation of newest Android Studio I tried to install Lombok plugin 
(Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 | Built on January 19, 2022)

But didn't find Lombok in **Settings -> Plugins -> Marketplace**

[image]

I found that the problem is:

[Plugin 'Lombok' is not compatible with Android Studio build AI-211.7628.21](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/1107)

Comment: you could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73349686/13773355) out to see if it helps!

Comment: "The Lombok IntelliJ Plugin should be bundled in Android Studio 2023.1.1.8."
see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/266333624 and https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/tree/master/plugins/lombok
Do NOT try to 'side-load' the current Lombok plugin: this breaks auto-completion in Android Studio (in some cases)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**How to fix it:**

- go to https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok/versions
- download .zip with the latest version (0.34.1-2019.1)
- unpack it to ~/android-studio/plugins (use your path to Android Studio)
- restart IDE

Comment: This worked for me on macOS 11.6.4, AS Bumblebee Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8193401

Comment: Worked!! Without any other fixing or editing!

Comment: i also use android studio version same as you but i follow above it doesnt work can you help me @DiegoTorresMilano

Comment: Didn't work on my machine, at least on version 2021.1.1 Patch 1 (from Feb 1 2022) (Linux) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGFak.png -> but the other solution with editing the plugin jar helped

Comment: Extracting to ~/android-studio/plugins folder helped me. Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3. Editing jar file didn't help me.

Comment: Worked for me. Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1 Patch 2

Answer (score 13):

After downloading the plugin file, version number needs to be changed.

I downloaded lombok-plugin-0.34-2020.2.zip from the releases (https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/releases), unzip it, went to the META-INF directory, open the jar file, changed in the xml file the line to `<idea-version since-build="191.6183" until-build="IE-212.*"/>` then saved the zip, installed the plugin from disk on Android Studio. Things seem to work - previous errors regarding unresolved getter functions now gone. Pretty brute force. Not sure if there will be side effects, but who knows if this plugin will only be updated after next year?

Edit: The best solution is to get rid of Lombok from your project.  It's very easy in Android Studio from Refactor->Delombok.

Comment: This should be marked as the solution. Should work for everyone, including flatpak users.  Thank you for suggesting this.

Comment: Very nice solution, you saved my time dude.

Comment: Thanks. The instructions are now available in this video https://youtu.be/A14hrtUeNWU

Comment: none of this (or other threads "solutions") worked for me, I spent 2 hours trying everything humanly possible...I am getting rid of lombok from my projects...RIP :( Googlers once again killed a good idea. I'm starting to hate that company...

Comment: Delombok doesn't show in the refactor section.

Comment: until-build="999.*" -> Future-proof ;-)

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT 2023-07:**

Using this "solution"does **break code auto completion** feature in some cases.
This is probably also true for other 'hackish' solutions listed on this page.

We should wait for lombok plugin to be part of Android Studio.

*"The Lombok IntelliJ Plugin should be bundled in Android Studio 2023.1.1.8"*
src: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/266333624

---

This issue is help for me!!!

https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/1028

1. Download latest Lombok Plugin [Lombok 0.34.1-2019.1](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/download?rel=true&updateId=108259)

> FYI, all plugin versions are available on [JetBrains Marketplace](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok/versions) and
> [Github](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/releases)

2. extract / unzip `lombok-plugin-0.34-2020.2.jar` from
   `lombok-plugin-0.34.1-2019.1.zip/lombok-plugin/lib/lombok-plugin-0.34.1-2019.1.jar`
3. extract `plugin.xml` from 
   `lombok-plugin-0.34.1-2019.1.jar\META-INF\plugin.xml` 
   and change
   `<idea-version since-build="191.6183" until-build="191.*">` 
   to
   `<idea-version since-build="191.6183" until-build="999.*">`

> Why 999? To be future-proof :)

4. Update / overwrite 
   `lombok-plugin-0.34.1-2019.1.jar\META-INF\plugin.xml` 
   with your modified `plugin.xml` file using this command: 
   `jar uf lombok-plugin-0.34-2020.2.jar META-INF\plugin.xml`
   then
5. Update / overwrite 
   `lombok-plugin-0.34.1-2019.1.zip/lombok-plugin/lib/lombok-plugin-0.34.1-2019.1.jar`
   with your modified `lombok-plugin-0.34.1-2019.1.jar` file
6. In Android Studio, select 'Install Plugin From Disk'
   [image]
7. Select the modified `lombok-plugin-0.34.1-2019.1.zip`
8. restart Android Studio
9. [image]

good luck.

Comment: now you should change `202.*` to `AI-221.6008.13`

Comment: now I use IntelliJ IDEA CE to develop Android application

Answer (score 1):

To solve Hedgehog problems with version 231.9392.1  you can download de jar and install as a local file.

[Link to jar]https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sgpublic/lombok-plugin-repository/repository/plugins/231.9392.1/lombok-231.9392.1.zip

[source]https://github.com/sgpublic/lombok-plugin-repository?tab=readme-ov-file